# JTextField only updates size when window size changes

Tags: java, swing, size, jtextfield

I have set my `JTextField` variable to update the text when I select my checkbox using an `ItemListener` variable. Although the text updates, the size does not update BUT only updates when I maximize or minimize the window. Do you have any idea why this happens?

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

class Fruitbox extends JFrame
{
    private JTextField Atext;
    private final JCheckBox Abox;
    private final JCheckBox Bbox;
    private String currentString;

        public Fruitbox()
        {
            super("Hey you da best");
            setLayout(new FlowLayout());

            Atext = new JTextField("Fruit");
            Abox = new JCheckBox("Apple");
            Bbox = new JCheckBox("Banana");

            add(Abox);
            add(Bbox);
            add(Atext);

            Trigger t = new Trigger();
            Abox.addItemListener(t);
            Bbox.addItemListener(t);
        }
            class Trigger implements ItemListener
            {
                    @Override
                    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
                    {
                    String S = "Fruit";
                    if(Abox.isSelected() && Bbox.isSelected())
                        S = "Apple and Banana";

                    else if(Abox.isSelected())
                        S = "Apple";

                    else if(Bbox.isSelected())
                        S = "Banana";

                    else
                        S = "Fruit";

                    Atext.setText(S);
                    }
            }
    }



    class MainFruit
    {
       public static void main(String[] args)
     {
        Fruitbox Fruit = new Fruitbox();
        Fruit.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Fruit.setSize(300,300);
        Fruit.setVisible(true);
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have the JTextField change size by calling `revalidate()` on the container that holds the JTextField from within your listener after setting its text as this has your layout managers re-layout the held components, but better overall is to make the JTextField larger to begin with by using a constructor that helps you set its columns. i.e., change this:

```
Atext = new JTextField("Fruit");
```

to this:

```
Atext = new JTextField("Fruit", 25); // or some suitable value
```

or better still

```
// avoid "magic" numbers by using constants and variables
Atext = new JTextField("Fruit", COLUMNS);  // where COLUMNS is a constant
```

---

Note that variable names by convention should start with a lower-case letter, and that by following these conventions, others will more easily understand your code.